# why a socket server container can't reach my redis server container even if

Tags: node.js, docker, sockets, redis

i have this docker compose that connects my redis server with my socket server that has redis client

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  redis-server:
    image: "redis"
    volumes:
      - express-chat-vol:/express-chat/
    networks:
      - express-chat-net
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
  socket-server:
    build:
      context: ./server/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.socketServer
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks:
      - express-chat-net
volumes:
  express-chat-vol:
networks:
  express-chat-net:
```

but socket server can't access the redis server and bring up this error and i'm stuck for 2 days now , how can i solve it ?

````
Starting token2_socket-server_1 ... done
Starting token2_redis-server_1  ... done
Attaching to token2_socket-server_1, token2_redis-server_1
redis-server_1   | 1:C 29 May 2022 01:07:22.191 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis-server_1   | 1:C 29 May 2022 01:07:22.191 # Redis version=7.0.0, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis-server_1   | 1:C 29 May 2022 01:07:22.191 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf 

//some logs
redis-server_1   | 1:M 29 May 2022 01:07:22.195 * Ready to accept connections
socket-server_1  | socket server is listening on port 5000
socket-server_1  | node:internal/process/promises:288
socket-server_1  |             triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
socket-server_1  |             ^
socket-server_1  | 
socket-server_1  | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
socket-server_1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1195:16)
socket-server_1  | Emitted 'error' event on Commander instance at:
socket-server_1  |     at RedisSocket.<anonymous> (/socketServer/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:339:14)
socket-server_1  |     at RedisSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
socket-server_1  |     at RedisSocket._RedisSocket_connect (/socketServer/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:127:14)
socket-server_1  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
socket-server_1  |     at async Commander.connect (/socketServer/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:163:9)
socket-server_1  |     at async connectRedisClient (/socketServer/socketServer.js:19:3) {
socket-server_1  |   errno: -111,
socket-server_1  |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
socket-server_1  |   syscall: 'connect',
socket-server_1  |   address: '127.0.0.1',
socket-server_1  |   port: 6379
socket-server_1  | }
socket-server_1  | 
socket-server_1  | Node.js v18.0.0
token2_socket-server_1 exited with code 1```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try using `redis-server` as the hostname and not `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: i'm doing that  
const Redis = require("redis");
const redisClient = Redis.createClient({
  host: "redis-server",
  port: 6379,
});

Comment: Is it working? If not remove the extra network definition and try again. Compose will create a network for you if you define none and maybe you're missing some configuration options.

Comment: actually it worked , the configuration of redis client wan't right , the right was : const redisClient = Redis.createClient({ url: 'redis://redis-server:6379' });